# output is different when I use default value vs user input

Tags: c

I am doing some pattern searching in a string for my homework. When I was testing the code, I declared a default value for easy testing. When I am done with the testing and tried to run the code using user input, the output is different.
The output (when used default value) "Match at position 4." but when use user input, it says "no match".

This is my code:

```
int main() {
    char text[255], pattern[255];
    char sensitive = 'N';
    int n, a[255], i, j, k = 0, l, found = 0, t = 0, temp=0;
    printf("Enter a sentence , up to 255 characters:");
    fgets(text, 255, stdin);
    text[strcspn(text, "\n")] = 0;
    printf("Enter a pattern , up to 255 characters:");
    fgets(pattern, 255, stdin);
    pattern[strcspn(pattern, "\n")] = 0;
    printf("Should the match be case-sensitive, Y or N?");
    scanf("%c", &sensitive);

    if (sensitive == 'N' || sensitive == 'n') {
        for (i = 0; i < strlen(text); i++) {
            text[i] = tolower(text[i]);
            //printf("%c", text[i]);
        }
        for (i = 0; i < strlen(pattern); i++) {
            pattern[i] = tolower(pattern[i]);
            //printf("%c", pattern[i]);

        }
    }

    for (i = 0;text[i] != '\0';i++)
    {
        j = 0;
        if (text[i] == pattern[j] || pattern[j] == '.')
        {
            temp = i + 1;
            while (text[i] == pattern[j] || pattern[j] == '.')
            {
                i++;
                j++;
            }

            if (pattern[j] == '\0')
            {
                temp -= 1;
                printf("Matches at position %d\n", temp);
                exit(0);
            }
            else
            {
                i = temp;
                temp = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    if (temp == 0)
        printf("No match.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are all your variables global?

Comment: "the output is different" how?

Comment: Please re-read your question and modify it as if a total stranger is trying to answer it.

Comment: Please read [ask] and produce a [mre]

Comment: `fgets` puts a `\n` at the end of the user input. Maybe that is a problem, but we cannot tell, because you don't show us the relevant code.

Comment: nope the modified code isnt working accurately

Comment: It works for me (after including the necessary header file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tests if text or pattern are at the terminating zero so the index does not go beyond the array boundary.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main ( void) {
    char text[255], pattern[255];
    char sensitive[3] = "N";
    int i, j, temp=0;
    printf ( "Enter a sentence , up to 255 characters:");
    if ( ! fgets(text, 255, stdin)) {
        fprintf ( stderr, "fgets problem [text]\n");
        return 0;
    }
    text[strcspn(text, "\n")] = 0;
    printf ( "Enter a pattern , up to 255 characters:");
    if ( ! fgets(pattern, 255, stdin)) {
        fprintf ( stderr, "fgets problem [pattern]\n");
        return 0;
    }
    pattern[strcspn(pattern, "\n")] = 0;//remove newline
    printf ( "Should the match be case-sensitive, Y or N?");
    if ( ! fgets( sensitive, sizeof sensitive, stdin)) {
        fprintf ( stderr, "fgets problem [sensitive]\n");
        return 0;
    }

    if ( sensitive[0] == 'N' || sensitive[0] == 'n') {
        for ( i = 0; text[i]; i++) {
            text[i] = tolower(text[i]);
        }
        for (i = 0; pattern[i]; i++) {
            pattern[i] = tolower(pattern[i]);
        }
    }

    for ( i = 0; text[i] != '\0';i++) {
        j = 0;
        temp = i + 1;
        while ( pattern[j] && text[i + j]
        && ( text[i + j] == pattern[j] || pattern[j] == '.')) {
            j++;
        }

        if (pattern[j] == '\0') {
            temp -= 1;
            printf("Matches at position %d\n", temp);
            exit(0);
        }
        else {
            temp = 0;
        }
    }

    if (temp == 0) {
        printf("No match.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```